# How to use @ConditionalOnBean with @Qualifier in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, aws-java-sdk

Currently, I have following two classes:

```
@Configuration
@Import(AssumeRoleSQSConfig.class)
public class AssumeRoleConfig {
    public static final DynamicStringProperty ROLE_ARN = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance()
            .getStringProperty("role.arn", null);
    public static final DynamicStringProperty ROLE_SESSION = DynamicPropertyFactory.getInstance()
            .getStringProperty("role.session.name", null);
    
    @Bean(name = "assumeRole")
    public AWSCredentialsProvider getCredentials() {
        if (ROLE_ARN.get() == null || ROLE_SESSION.get() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ... omitted ...
    }
}
```

And, I have both the properties set in my config.properties.

```
@Configuration
public class AssumeRoleSQSConfig {
    @Bean(name = "sqsAssumeBean")
    @ConditionalOnBean(name = "assumeRole")
    public AmazonSQSAsync sqsAssume(
        @Qualifier("assumeRole") AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentials) {
        ... omitted ...
    }
}
```

I also have these two default beans:

```
@Configuration
@Import(DefaultSQSConfig.class)
public class DefaultCredentialsConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AWSCredentialsProvider defaultCred() {
        return new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class DefaultSQSConfig {
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    @Primary
    public AmazonSQSAsync defaultSQS() {
        ... omitted ...
    }
}
```

If another class tries to get access to "sqsAssumeBean" and "defaultSQS" like so:

```
@Configuration
@Import({DefaultCredentialsConfig.class, AssumeRoleConfig.class})
public class QueueConfig {
    
    private AmazonSQSAsync defaultSQS;
    private AmazonSQSAsync assumeRoleSQS;

    @Autowired
    public QueueConfig (
        @Qualifier("defaultSQS") AmazonSQSAsync defaultSQS,
        @Qualifier("sqsAssumeBean") AmazonSQSAsync assumeRoleSQS) {
        this.defaultSQS = defaultSQS;
        this.assumeRoleSQS = assumeRoleSQS;
    }
}
```

Then, I get following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'queueConfig' defined in ... QueueConfig.class 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="sqsAssumeBean")}

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in QueueConfig required a bean of type 'com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - User-defined bean method 'defaultSQS' in 'DefaultSQSConfig'
```

From what I understand so far, QueueConfig constructor looks for the bean "sqsAssumeBean", but it could not find "assumeRole" bean as it is not created yet. So, the QueueConfig constructor looks for the "defaultSQS" bean instead of the "sqsAssumeBean", but it could not get injected as @Qualifier is looking for "assumeRole" bean specifically.

I debugged the application and found that AssumeRoleConfig "getCredentials" method does not even get called. Which means that AssumeRoleSQSConfig does not even try to fetch the bean "assumeRole", but it does try to fetch if I remove @ConditionalOnBean.
Why is @ConditionalOnBean takes the initiative and finds that there is no "assumeRole" bean created instead, letting "assumeRole" bean to be created and if it is null, then take the initiative and declare that there is no "assumeRole" bean? Thank you!

(Note: I have ROLE_ARN and ROLE_SESSION dynamic property. So, what I am trying to do is if ROLE_ARN/ROLE_SESSION dynamic property is not set/null, then "assumeRole" bean should not be created. That should also conditionally not create "sqsAssumeBean". That should also conditionally not create "queueConfig" bean. But, currently, even though I have those two dynamic properties set, the method that creates "assumeRole" bean does not get called at all.)

Comment: It might work with `@Autowired(required = false)`

Comment: No changes. I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is to inject the optional dependencies.

There're three most preferred ways to achieve it:

1. Use `org.springframework.lang.Nullable` annotation at the parameter level
2. Make the params optional with `java.util.Optional`
3. Define multiple `@Autowired(required = false)` constructors with the only required arguments defined

[Spring @Autowired Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation)

Comment: I tried all three options, but "sqsAssumeBean" is still not getting created (I get NPE). I think my question was little unclear. I edited it. I actually want "assumeRole" bean to be created before "sqsAssumeBean". But, don't want to create "sqsAssumeBean" when "assumeRole" is null. But, even though I have those two dynamic property set (which means the "assumeRole" bean should not be null if it gets created), the method that creates "assumeRole" bean is not called at all. Therefore, @ConditionalOnBean thinks that there is no "assumeRole" bean. I hope this helps.

Comment: The beans should've been created in the regular order as there're no circular dependencies defined. I would suggest to review the configuration - whether the `@Import` annotations are even necessary for that mappings and whether the `assumeRole` bean was really created. You have to debug the `getCredentials()` factory method as well to test if it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but have you tried `@AutoConfigureAfter` and `@AutoConfigureBefore`